# Magento 2 Checkout page . Why not display Price shipping in page checkout?

Tags: magento2, checkout, shipping

**Question 1.** Please help me . I custom my theme and page checkout. I write file `checkout_index_index_.xml` in my theme for render page checkout. But it don't display shipping method, price for `Flat Rate` or `Best Way`. In this picture . So I can't checkout my cart.

.
[image]
 So , I can't checkout my cart.

I just copy file `checkout_index_index.xml` to `<mytheme>\<layout>checkout_index_index.xml` . 
So , please help me resolve this it.

**Question 2.** I don't understand about this code. Please help me

[image]

`ko foreach: $parent.getRegion('price')` . 
What is $parent? And this line do what?

Comment: Have u found any solution?

Comment: Have u found any solution? :/